# What is the up-to-date disposition towards narcolepsy in the U.S.A. for obtaining a pilot license?

Tags: faa-regulations, medical

Citation: [What medical conditions does the FAA consider disqualifying?](https://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/medical_certification/faq/response6/)

In the past, I recall this page having listed narcolepsy, but I find no mention of narcolepsy anywhere relevant on the FAA website anymore. Can anyone enlighten me as to whether I am just missing it somewhere, or if there is knowledge of this specifically having been changed? It would surprise me greatly if this were not a disqualifying condition, but I want to find official information on it.

Comment: I would hope that a condition that makes you suddenly fall asleep out of the blue would be disqualifying...

Comment: @Sean that's actually a misconception about narcolepsy- while possible, lots of people have much more mild forms of narcolepsy that only manifest as daytime drowsiness.

Comment: Which is still extremely dangerous in a pilot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [FAA Guide For Medical Examiner](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/media/guide.pdf)s there is only a single direct reference to narcolepsy

Under the Obstructive Sleep Apnea QA section it states

> **Does this process involve other sleep disorder conditions? (E.g.
>   Period Limb Movement Disorder, narcolepsy, central sleep apnea, etc.)?**
>
> No. This process is for obstructive sleep apnea only. *If it is clear
>   that the airman suffers from a different sleep disorder, DEFER and
>   submit any supporting documentation for FAA decision.*

This would indicate that if you suffer from any sleep disorder conditions your medical should be DEFERed

Earlier in the document it states:

> Medical conditions that chronically interfere with sleep are
>   disqualifying regardless of whether a sleep aid is used or not.
>   Examples may include primary sleep disorders (e.g., insomnia, sleep
>   apnea) or psychological disorders (e.g., anxiety, depression). While
>   sleep aids may be appropriate and effective for short term symptomatic
>   relief, the primary concern should be the diagnosis, treatment, and
>   resolution of the underlying condition before clearance for aviation
>   duties.

[Narcolepsy is a sleep disorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcolepsy) and would potentially fall under this definition and thus prevent your from getting clearance.

In these cases its usually [best to get the advice of an FAA AME.](https://www.faa.gov/pilots/amelocator/)

Comment: Thank you for this very direct and cited information. I really appreciate it.